# What was the red (rasengan type) thing Boruto's giant rasengan collided with, while attacking Momoshki?

Tags: boruto

[image]

During the final battle with Momoshiki Otsuki, Boruto uses giant Rasengan to attack, which was defended by Otsuki, with a red ball of his own. Was it Boruto's earlier Rasengan, which he absorbed?